# Search results as JSON in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, json

Is it possible to get search results from ArcGIS Online and ArcGIS OpenData as JSON?

When I search for, say 'population', the URL generated is either http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=population&t=content or http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=population

Can I append something to the URL to get a JSON response rather than an HTML page?

Comment: Sorry, thought you are querying services.